# drop rows if the two columns have non-missing values but have different values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

```
sender_name receiver_name
NaN         Carl
Carl        Carl
Peter       Carl
Carlos      Matt
Julia       Bernard
Carlos      NaN
Peter       NaN
NaN         Matt
...
```

I want to drop if sender_name != receiver_name

If i do

```
df=df.drop(xfers_dex['name_sender'] != xfers_dex['name_receiver'])
```

It drops all rows with `NaN` values..

I only want to drop if both columns have non-missing values. so my desired df

```
sender_name receiver_name
NaN         Carl
Carl        Carl
Carlos      NaN
Peter       NaN
NaN         Matt
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
df[(df['sender_name'] == df['receiver_name']) | (df.isnull().any(axis=1))]
```

Output:

```
  sender_name receiver_name
0         NaN          Carl
1        Carl          Carl
5      Carlos           NaN
6       Peter           NaN
7         NaN          Matt
```

Comment: OP wants to drop, not to keep the rows you need to use `!=` not `==` also the second condition could be `df.isnull().any(axis=1)` ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my answer. My output matches the wanted output - so, I guess, I am dropping all unwanted rows. Or am I missing something? Moreover, I am not sure whether the OP wants or not to drop the rows with two `NaN`: that is why I did not use `any`. :-)

Comment: no you're right my bad, the second part of the comment stands (`any` is more straightforward than `sum`+comparison). In any case you already have my vote

Comment: Thanks, @mozway! `any` is `True` if there is more than one `NaN` -- and that is what I am not sure the OP wants! In reality, it appears a bit absurd wanting to keep a row with *two* `NaN`... So, maybe the best is doing as you advise: using `any` -- and I have just done so!

Answer (score 0):

Extend the condition so it also checks that values are different than NaN:

```py
df=df.drop((xfers_dex['name_sender'] != xfers_dex['name_receiver']) & (xfers_dex['name_receiver'] != 'NaN') & (xfers_dex['name_sender'] != 'NaN'))
```